# Google map does not fit in SubView properly

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using Google map but it's not set properly in `subView`.
I am using swift 3.

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapSubView: UIView!
 var mapView:GMSMapView!
var placesClient: GMSPlacesClient!
```

I have used the following code in `viewDidLoad`:

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 28.616536, longitude: 77.379552, zoom: 12.0)
mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: mapSubView.bounds, camera: camera)
mapSubView.addSubview(mapView)
mapView.delegate = self
self.drawPath()
placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.shared()
```

Screenshot from my simulator:

You have see white space in right side near google map

[image]

And a screenshot from my storyboard:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In `viewDidLoad`, your view is not completely rendered so the line

```
mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: mapSubView.bounds, camera: camera)
```

will set the size of the mapView based on the bounds at that particular time. There are a couple of work arounds. One is to render your mapView at a later time e.g. in `viewWillAppear`. The other is to create a `UIView` in storyboard, set it's constraints, make it's class to be `GMSMapView` and connect an `@IBOutlet`. Also, you can fix it by using `autoresizingMask`